# Cancel concrete forming on a bukkit server

Tags: java, bukkit

I am trying to cancel the forming of concrete powder and water to concrete on my bukkit server on 1.17.1.

I already tried to cancel the `BlockFormEvent`. This works perfectly for the current block I am placing. But when a block gets placed next to a concrete powder block, which is near water, the powder will form into concrete. How do I stop the powder to form to concrete in this case (on block update?).

Answer (score 0):

You should use the `BlockSpreadEvent` event which is called when grass changed to dirt etc...

Code example:

```java
@EventHandler
public void onSpread(BlockSpreadEvent e) {
    // if it's a colored concrete powder
   if(e.getNewState().getType().name().contains("CONCRETE_POWDER")) {
       e.setCancelled(true); // cancel
   }
}
```

[Documentation](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/bukkit/org/bukkit/event/block/BlockSpreadEvent.html)